# What function/module that write oauth info (token, user etc) into mnesia in ejabberd_oauth.erl?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I'm trying to understand how ejabberd_oauth.erl implementing the oauth. Inside the ejabberd_oauth.erl, there is a function name **associate_access_token** - this is where **mnesia:dirty_write(R)** located. Based on my understanding, **mnesia:dirty_write(R)** should write the record into the DB but I totally wrong after completed the test.

**Test** : I've commented the whole function and run the oauth, then dump_table to check the latest DB content. The DB that I just dumped still contain the latest token. This is means that the write-into-the-db is controlled by another function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the right function for that operation. The oauth key is written in `ejabberd_oauth:associate_access_token`. Are you sure your test is correct ?

Comment: I'm totally sure about my test. I even **rename (make typo)** mnesia:dirty_write(R) to be something like mnesia:dirtysz_write(R). My test proved that associate_access_token don't even detect / check the syntax error of mnesia:dirty_write(R). Could you help to give me any other hint?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a quick solution for my issue :

Custom module need to be ​*named*​ as "ejabberd_oauth", *compile* and ​*copy*​ the new ejabberd_oauth.beam into /lib/ejabberd-/ebin/ 
(this will replace the default ejabberd_oauth.beam).

So the answer to my question : *associate_access_token*

Previously (that lead me to the issue) I :

1. Renamed the original ejabberd_oauth.erl to the new name, compile and
   run it.
2. Didn't uninstall the default *ejabberd_oauth* module. So
   this I think made my ejabberd server has two authentication module
   and confused the server.
3. Configured ejabberd.yml as "/oauth : my_custom_ejabberd_oauth"